# Difference between numpy.float and numpy.float64

Tags: python, numpy, types

There seems to be a subtle difference between `numpy.float` and `numpy.float64`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> isinstance(2.0, np.float)
True
>>> isinstance(2.0, np.float64)
False
```

Can someone clarify this? Thanks

Comment: `numpy.float` is Python's float class. Do you mean `numpy.float_` with an underscore at the end? That is the same as `numpy.float64`.

Comment: I meant numpy.float without underscore. Would you elaborate your comments, maybe into an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`np.float` is an alias for python `float` type. 
`np.float32` and `np.float64` are numpy specific 32 and 64-bit float types.

```
float?
Init signature: float(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
float(x) -> floating point number

Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.
Type:           type

np.float?
Init signature: np.float(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
float(x) -> floating point number

Convert a string or number to a floating point number, if possible.
Type:           type

np.float32?
Init signature: np.float32(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:      32-bit floating-point number. Character code 'f'. C float compatible.
File:           c:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py
Type:           type

np.float64?
Init signature: np.float64(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:      64-bit floating-point number. Character code 'd'. Python float compatible.
File:           c:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py
Type:           type
```

Thus, when you do `isinstance(2.0, np.float)`, it is equivalent to `isinstance(2.0, float)` as 2.0 is a plain python built-in float type... and not the numpy type.

`isinstance(np.float64(2.0), np.float64)` would obviously be `True`.

Comment: I had an arrival delay time that was `float64`. When I converted the departure delay time type from `int64` to match the arrival delay type, I didn't catch that I used `fillna().astype('float')` and the data/scatter plot changed a lot. I couldn't figure out what was going on. When I corrected it to `fillna().astype('float64')` all was good. Not sure why it made such a difference when all the values looked like `55.00, 130.00` etc.

Answer (score -6):

This would seem to be the difference between a 32-bit floating point number and a 64-bit floating point number (in C, a float vs. a double), and 2.0 ends up being a 32-bit floating point number.

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote: Your answer seems wrong. Here is what I just tried: isinstance(1e200, np.float64), which gives false. In addition,  isinstance(2.0, np.float32) gives false too.